# String returned by variable not working like the same string entered manually

Tags: php, string, session-variables

I am trying to make some adjustments to uploadify.php which comes with the latest version of uploadify (3.0 beta), so that it works with a session variable that stores the login username and adds it to the path for uploads.  Here is uploadify.php as it currently looks:

```
<?php
session_name("MyLogin");
session_start();

$targetFolder = '/songs/' . $_SESSION['name']; // Relative to the root

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
    $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') .'/'. $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array('m4a','mp3','flac','ogg'); // File extensions
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        echo '1';
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
}

echo $targetFolder;

?>
```

I added `echo $targetFolder;` at the bottom so that I could make sure that the string returned was correct, and it is, i.e. '/songs/nick'.  For some reason though, uploads are not going to the correct folder, i.e. the username folder, but instead are going to the parent folder 'songs'.  The folder for username exists, with correct permissions, and when I manually enter `$targetFolder = '/songs/nick';` all works fine.  Which strikes me as rather strange.  I have limited experience of using php, but wonder how if the correct string is returned by the session variable, the upload works differently than with the manually entered string.

Any help would be much appreciated.  It's the last issue with a website that was due to go live 2 days ago!

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: Not an answer, but note that the `'name'` is sent by the client *(browser)*, and could include malicious data, and should not be trusted -- one could send a file named test.mp3 that would contain some non-mp3 content ;;; you should generate your own name, when saving the file, first ; and use http://www.php.net/fileinfo to analyse the content-type of a file, instead of trusting the extension sent by the user.

Comment: Have you tried to echo `$targetFile` and see what value it contains before `move_uploaded_file()` call?

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 Thanks, but I'm not sure how I would echo `$targetFile` as this would only be generated on an upload, which takes place on my index.php page

Answer (score 0):

Hy

Try use `'songs/'` , without the first '/'

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work, either with the manual path or the path including the variable